iOS how to make VariableBlur's CIFilter darker?
I am using the VariableBlur library in Swift to create a blur over my collection view under the status bar area as such:

I am trying to figure out how I can make the blur darker?
The library uses a CIFilter but I am not sure what to change to make it darker. I have already tried changing the UIBlurEffect(style: .regular) to use .dark but that didn't make any difference.
And the color0 on ciGradientFilter is already set to black. In fact, changing it to red or any other color doesn't make any difference.

The existing makeGradientImage is already making a gradient image, with color0 set to black as you have observed. The existing code uses this as a mask, but you can display this image in your own CALayer, which is added as a sibling of the backdropLayer.
open class VariableBlurUIView: UIVisualEffectView {

    let darkLayer = CALayer()
    
    public init(maxBlurRadius: CGFloat = 20, direction: VariableBlurDirection = .blurredTopClearBottom, startOffset: CGFloat = 0) {
        super.init(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .regular))

        // ...

        let gradientImage = makeGradientImage(startOffset: startOffset, direction: direction)

        variableBlur.setValue(maxBlurRadius, forKey: "inputRadius")
        variableBlur.setValue(gradientImage, forKey: "inputMaskImage")
        variableBlur.setValue(true, forKey: "inputNormalizeEdges")

        let backdropLayer = subviews.first?.layer

        backdropLayer?.filters = [variableBlur]
        
        darkLayer.contents = gradientImage
        darkLayer.zPosition = -1
        backdropLayer?.superLayer?.addSublayer(darkLayer)
        
        for subview in subviews.dropFirst() {
            subview.alpha = 0
        }
    }
    
    open override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        darkLayer.frame = subviews.first?.layer.frame ?? .zero
    }

    // ...

}

Side-by-side comparison:
 

Do you know why the gradient end at the bottom has a bit of a sudden transparent line instead of it being smooth? Hard to show it but more obvious when scrolling and when content under it is light. For example, with white color, it's very obvious: https://i.imgur.com/dADDkLt.jpeg

unfortunately, it still shows the sudden transparent line. The Photos app doesn't seem to have this issue.

those end up moving that line to half the height. You may not see the line at first but if you look at it against a white background, then you will notice it I think. It's not visible with the image you are using in your answer. The line is present even if we disable the blur. The gradient is the cause of the problem. I wonder if I can set the gradient so that it's more darker in the first 1/3rd and less darker afterwards?

@sudoExclamationExclamation Well that would be darkLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.3333333], but I doubt that would change anything. The idea of putting the layer as a sibling is so that darkLayer is also affected by the blur, which I expect would remove the line. Try putting a totally black layer instead of a CAGradientLayer. It should be blurred, but is there still a line?

@sudoExclamationExclamation Actually, I don't need to use CAGradientLayer at all. The existing makeGradientImage method is already making a black-to-clear gradient. Just display that in a regular CALayer! I have updated the answer.

your way of using the existing makeGradientImage method worked well! I was also able to tweak the color0 value from black to CIColor(color: UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)) instead for a more subtle look. Thanks!

    /*To adjust the darkness of a real-time blur effect over a scrolling UICollectionView using the VariableBlurView*/
    
import UIKit
import CoreImage
import VariableBlurView

class DarkenedVariableBlurView: VariableBlurView {

    override func applyBlurEffect() {
        super.applyBlurEffect()
        
        // Access the existing CIFilter used for blurring
        guard let blurFilter = self.currentBlurFilter else { return }
        
        // Create a CIColorControls filter to adjust brightness and contrast
        let colorControlsFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")!
        colorControlsFilter.setValue(blurFilter.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        colorControlsFilter.setValue(-0.5, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey) // Darkening effect
        colorControlsFilter.setValue(1.2, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)    // Increase contrast
        
        // Apply the filter chain and update the view's content
        if let darkenedOutput = colorControlsFilter.outputImage {
            self.updateView(with: darkenedOutput)
        }
    }
    
    private func updateView(with image: CIImage) {
        let context = CIContext()
        if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(image, from: image.extent) {
            self.layer.contents = cgImage
        }
    }
}

/*
Replace VariableBlurView with your Custom DarkenedVariableBlurView:
Use your DarkenedVariableBlurView class in the view that overlays your UICollectionView.*/

//If VariableBlurView already updates in real-time as the collection view scrolls, then your custom filter should apply dynamically without additional code. If not, ensure that your view is updated in the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method:

extension YourViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let blurView = yourCustomBlurView as? DarkenedVariableBlurView {
            blurView.applyBlurEffect()
        }
    }
}

please try with this :)

Wouldn't this be extremely poor performance as it's redoing it each time scrollViewDidScroll is called?

//import CoreImage

func applyVariableBlurAndDarken(to image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else { return nil }
     // Apply VariableBlur Filter
    let variableBlurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIMaskedVariableBlur")!
    variableBlurFilter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    variableBlurFilter.setValue(10.0, forKey: "inputRadius")  // Adjust the blur radius as needed
    
    guard let blurredImage = variableBlurFilter.outputImage else { return nil }
    
    // Apply Color Controls to darken the image
    let colorControlsFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")!
    colorControlsFilter.setValue(blurredImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    colorControlsFilter.setValue(-0.5, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey) // Reduce brightness to darken
    colorControlsFilter.setValue(1.2, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)   // Optional: increase contrast
    
    guard let darkenedImage = colorControlsFilter.outputImage else { return nil }
    
    // Render the final image
    let context = CIContext()
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(darkenedImage, from: darkenedImage.extent) else { return nil }
    
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}

// Usage
if let image = UIImage(named: "your_image_name") {
    let processedImage = applyVariableBlurAndDarken(to: image)
    // Now you can use the processedImage
}


This is applying it to a static image. The VariableBlurView library I am using allows real time blur over a scrolling UICollectionView. Do you know how I can do that?

Hey ,
Try with below solution :)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
